Magento 1 - Back Order Issues - How do I see which products are in-stock but still have a back order against them?
Ref: Magento 1 Store: I am trying to understand how I can run a report that shows all products that have been placed onto a back order, but are actually now in stock and just need fulfilling to clear the back-orders? Currently our back orders are found by selecting Reports then Custom Reports then Deferred Income.
I am sure there are some very clever people out there who can resolve this in a blink of an eye!!
